# Is it safe to use same client certificate app-wide?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, grpc, client-certificates

Lets say I have mobile app and a server which communicate through TLS-encrypted gRPC API (or any HTTP TLS API for that matter).

I want server to check client certificate as extra protection layer (not primary authentication mechanism).

Is it safe to ship app binary with the same client certificate+key pair, or does it make MiTM attack possible, for instance if someone would reverse-engineer app binary and obtain client certificate+key, would it be possible to recover session keys and decrypt traffic?

Comment: *"Is it safe..."* depends on your threat model. Does your threat model include attackers reverse engineering your binary, extracting the key and certificate, and then using them? If NO, then there are no problems. If YES, then there are problems. Don't laugh at the model or question. The web security model used by browsers removes attacks that are inconvenient for them to contain. The browsers do it all the time, and it includes the number one threat known to man - user phishing.

Comment: @jww yes, lets consider that reverse engineering is in threat model.

Comment: The NO, it is not safe.

Comment: Client certificates are usually used to authenticate people, not apps. It just doesn't make sense to have an app-specific key, unless the app is somehow customized to be unique per person.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TLS 1.2 protocol and the certificate certifies the signing key (this is the case for gRPC), MITM attack is not possible as far as client verifies the server's certificate and server's certificate is not compromised. MITM attack is not possible even if client does not use certificate.

However, the value of adding client certificate and using mutual TLS is not clear. What "extra protection layer" do you want to achieve? If you hardcode a private key in client app, you know it could be reverse-engineered given enough effort.

Comment: Now we have two contradicting answers about mitm safety, can you pinpoint RFC place, which proves its security?

I had two arguments in favour of client certificates:
• Increase effort needed to do any research on server's API
• Client certificates can be used as app API keys and can be created in straightforward way for new parties in the future